# INSERT INTO SELECT gives: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, insert-into

I'm getting this error message when executing the code below.

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
       --DROP TABLE #UniqueBuildingUsageFkAndBuildingFk
         CREATE TABLE #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk (
         Building_fk INT NOT NULL 
         ,Usage_fk INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
         );

         ;WITH UnknownUsageFkAndBuildingFkCTE AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT mm.Building_fk, 0 AS Usage_fk FROM Customers.StandardizedRecord sr
        JOIN Customers.MidasMatch mm ON mm.CustomersBuildingNumberKey = sr.CustomersBuildingNumberKey
        WHERE sr.CustomersBuildingNumberKey NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT emm.CustomersBuildingNumberKey FROM
        [Customers].[CustomersBuildingNumberKeyCustomersUsageXRef] ebu 
        JOIN [Customers].[MidasMatch] emm ON emm.CustomersBuildingNumberKey = ebu.CustomersBuildingNumberKey WHERE emm.Building_fk > 0)
        AND mm.Building_fk > 0 
        ) 
        INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk 
        SELECT Building_fk, Usage_fk
        FROM UnknownUsageFkAndBuildingFkCTE;
```

But when I comment out the INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk line I'm returning the desired resultset.

I'm lost...

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT mm.Building_fk, 0 AS Usage_fk , 0 as CustomersBuildingNumberKey FROM Customers     -- there is a quick hint     with the follow-up  SELECT Building_fk, Usage_fk , CustomersBuildingNumberKey

Comment: The numbers of columns that your inserting into the table and the columns in your table are not equal.mention the columns names in your insert statement as `INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk (Building_fk, Usage_fk)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But that is a typo. My temp table indeed has only the Building_fk, Usage_fk columns. So, it's still an issue. I updated my code in the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table `#UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk` you have 3 columns (`Building_fk, Usage_fk, CustomersBuildingNumberKey`). So while insert into to this table you have to specify values for these three column

```
INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk 
SELECT Building_fk, Usage_fk, 0
FROM UnknownUsageFkAndBuildingFkCTE;
```

or you can specify the column in your insert

```
INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk (Building_fk, Usage_fk)
SELECT Building_fk, Usage_fk
FROM UnknownUsageFkAndBuildingFkCTE;
```

Comment: Abdul, Thanks for pointing it out. But that is a typo. My temp table indeed has only the Building_fk, Usage_fk columns. So, it's still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Abdul's answer above I realized I've missed the  `(Building_fk, Usage_fk)` in the line

```
INSERT INTO #UniqueUsageFkAndBuildingFk
```