# I am stuck in a situation where I am creating a table and according to the table I want to create a procedure, but it's showing an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am getting stuck in a situation, where I am creating a table and according to the table i want to create a procedure, but its showing an error.

I will provide snaps of that errors and i will provide table structure and proc structure:

Please help.. thank you

Table :

```
create table Students_Table
(
    Student_ID bigint not null,
    Student_Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    Student_Enrollment_No bigint not null,
    Student_Library_ID bigint,
    Student_Gender nvarchar(15) not null,
    Student_Phone nvarchar(15) not null,
    Student_Email nvarchar(100) not null,
    Student_Division nvarchar(30) not null,
    Student_Current_Semester nvarchar(20) not null,
    Student_Password nvarchar(80) not null,
    Photo_Name nvarchar(MAX),
    Photo_Size bigint,
    Photo_Binary varbinary(MAX),
    Username nvarchar(20),
    Student_Address nvarchar(100),
    Year nvarchar(10),
    Shift nvarchar(10),
    Roll_Number int,
    Parents_Contact nvarchar(15)
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
create proc Insert_Student
    @Student_Name nvarchar(50),
    @Roll int,
    @Student_Enrollment_No bigint,
    @Student_Library_ID bigint,
    @Student_Gender nvarchar(15),
    @Student_Phone nvarchar(15),
    @Student_Email nvarchar(100),
    @Student_Division nvarchar(30),
    @Student_Current_Semester nvarchar(20),
    @Username nvarchar(20),
    @Student_Address nvarchar(100),
    @Student_Password nvarchar(80),
    @Student_Shift nvarchar(10),
    @Student_Year nvarchar(10),
    @PContacts nvarchar(15),
    @Photo_Name nvarchar(max),
    @Photo_Size int,
    @Photo_Binary varbinary(max),
    @New_ID int output
as
begin
    Insert into Students_Table
    values (@Student_Name, @Student_Enrollment_No, @Student_Library_ID,
            @Student_Gender, @Student_Phone, @Student_Email,
            @Student_Division, @Student_Current_Semester, @Student_Password,
            @Photo_Name, @Photo_Size, @Photo_Binary,
            @Username, @Student_Address, @Student_Year, @Student_Shift,
            @Roll, @PContacts)

    select @New_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
end
```

This is the error I am getting :

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_Student, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 80]
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: `number of supplied values does not match table definition` - this is a big clue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO SELECT gives: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733574/insert-into-select-gives-column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-matc)

Comment: There are way too many things wrong here to just provide an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The number of columns in your insert query is not matching with the number of columns. So Specify the column names:

```
Insert into Students_Table (Student_Name ,Student_Enrollment_No,Student_Library_ID,...)
Values (@Student_Name,@Student_Enrollment_No, @Student_Library_ID, ... )
```

If you don't want to specify the column names, then the Student_ID should be specified as auto increment identity.

Comment: I done it, its successfully executed but in my site, its still showing error, can you please visit : http://prpsc.co.in/Students/BuildProfile.aspx
and try to register an demo account, and see the error when you click finish after filling all the fields

Comment: This Error :Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error its due to the difference in the values you are providing to insert. Your table requires 19 fields and you are providing 18. You need either to change the Id to make it autoincremental or provide the Id in your insert statement.

Comment: its an output parameter

Comment: If that's the case, you should change the column definition for the Id, to make it autoincremental. Otherwise, insert statement will expect a value for the Id.